# Networkx; move edges in nx.MultiDiGraph plot

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphviz, networkx, directed-graph

The question is very simple. However, neither official documentation or searching has helped much. I am looking to create something that (in a simple case) looks like this:

[image]

I am looking to plot a very simple directed graph, with one node, and *two* self-loops. This is what I got so far.

```
import networkx as nx
from nxpd import draw
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.graph['dpi'] = 120
{'state': 'Low'}
G.add_nodes_from(range(1,2))
G.add_edges_from([(1,1),(1,1)])
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
draw(G, show='ipynb')
```

Which produces

[image]

But, I would very much like that the other edge was on the *left*, and of equal size to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Graphviz to draw the graph with the draw() command there.  The attribute settings for Graphviz are documented at http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs

In your case you want to use "headport" and "tailport" to set where the edges meet the node.

Try

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,1,headport='sw',tailport='nw')
G.add_edge(1,1,headport='se',tailport='ne')
nx.write_dot(G,'sl.dot')
# run dot -Tpng sl.dot >sl.png
```

[image]

The documentation